# Xamarin forms WebRTC share screen

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, signalr, webrtc

I am trying to create a xamarin forms project that can share a screen in a conference connection. I am using the combination of SignalR and WebRTC. I can create the server and the client in an asp.net core API and Xamarin forms respectively.

I am having trouble implementing screen sharing on the xamarin forms application. I have tried using API and Signal R to make changes to images, but I Ideally need to share the screen of the device like a live video.

Comment: "I am having trouble" is not a useful description of the problem.  Are you getting an error or exception?  Please show the relevant code.

Comment: I cannot even find the path to implement anything, talk less of having an error. Do you know how to implement screen sharing in a xamarin form solution, using webRTC?

Comment: Possible starting point: https://youtu.be/2uTgzzZ3yPk

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me check it out. If i can derive the answer to this problem, I will post a detailed explanation and paste the link here.